# Solve for parameter value (complex) for zero determinant

Tags: equation-solving

I am new to mathematica (less then a month), with the discussion available on this platform and with some tutorial available I have manage to write a code (not a smart one) to solve for the parameter values (values can be real or complex) for which the determinant is zero using **Reduce** function.

### **Objective:** Search for value of **'sb'** for which the **det(DCoeffMat)** is zero for different values of **'Pb'**

```
(*%%% Parameters %%%%*)
ClearAll[sb, Pb, b, gama, L, w, h, Y, MI, EI, mu, rho, A, CN]
L = 10;
w = 0.02;
h = 0.02;
Y = 209*10^9;
MI = w*(h^3)/12;
EI = Y*MI;
mu = 0.001;
rho = 7800;
A = w*h;
CN = 4*Pi*mu/(Log[2*L/w] + 0.5) // N;
gama = rho*A*EI/(CN^2*L^4)
Do[B = b /. NSolve[b^4 + Pb*b^2 + sb + gama*sb^2 == 0, b] // N;
     DCoeffMat = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {B[[1]]^3 + Pb*B[[1]], 
     B[[2]]^3 + Pb*B[[2]], B[[3]]^3 + Pb*B[[3]], 
     B[[4]]^3 + Pb*B[[4]]}, {B[[1]]*Exp[B[[1]]], B[[2]]*Exp[B[[2]]], 
     B[[3]]*Exp[B[[3]]], 
     B[[4]]*Exp[B[[4]]]}, {B[[1]]^2*Exp[B[[1]]] + Pb*Exp[B[[1]]], 
     B[[2]]^2*Exp[B[[2]]] + Pb*Exp[B[[2]]], 
     B[[3]]^2*Exp[B[[3]]] + Pb*Exp[B[[3]]], 
     B[[4]]^2*Exp[B[[4]]] + Pb*Exp[B[[4]]]}};
 DA = Det[DCoeffMat];
 Print[Reduce[
     DA == 0 && -1000 < Re[sb] < 1000 && -1000 < Im[sb] < 1000, sb] //
     Quiet // N]
 , {Pb, 0.1, 4., 0.1}]
```

### Here is the equation used for finding **B** [image: Polynomial for solving **"b"**]

### Here is the matrix whose determinant is equated to zero [image]

On running the program its showing an error.

Am I missing something???

As per the literature from where the problem is pick up it says that for **pb<2.4674** the roots of **sb** has small real part (with non zero imaginary part) and after that its real value increases.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't use `NSolve` with `sb` as a parameter. You're missing a `;` after the `// N` and before `DCoeffMat`. And it's unlikely that `Reduce` will be able to solve your equation. You will most likely need to use `FindRoot` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I found that NSolve can give the four roots of the polynomial equation. Can Findroot function give complex roots???

Comment: Sure `FindRoot` can give complex roots, e.g., `FindRoot[x^2 - 3 I, {x, 1}]`.

Comment: @Carl, I have replaced the solver with the code `FindRoot[DA, {sb, I}] `, its working. But I want vary the initial point (in the above case I have given 0+0*I). How can I do that within the Do loop?? With the motive to find different solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a good idea to start variable names with capitals, hence the renaming below.

```
ll = 10;
w = 0.02;
h = 0.02;
yy = 209*10^9;
mi = w*(h^3)/12;
ei = yy*mi;
mu = 0.001;
rho = 7800;
aa = w*h;
cn = 4*Pi*mu/(Log[2*ll/w] + 0.5) // N;
gama = rho*aa*ei/(cn^2*ll^4);
```

Now define the functions of interest so they only operate on explicit numeric input.

```
bB[pb_?NumericQ, sb_?NumericQ] := 
  b /. NSolve[b^4 + pb*b^2 + sb + gama*sb^2 == 0, b];
dCoeffMat[pb_?NumericQ, sb_?NumericQ] := 
 With[{b = bB[pb, sb]}, {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {b[[1]]^3 + pb*b[[1]], 
    b[[2]]^3 + pb*b[[2]], b[[3]]^3 + pb*b[[3]], 
    b[[4]]^3 + pb*b[[4]]}, {b[[1]]*Exp[b[[1]]], b[[2]]*Exp[b[[2]]], 
    b[[3]]*Exp[b[[3]]], 
    b[[4]]*Exp[b[[4]]]}, {b[[1]]^2*Exp[b[[1]]] + pb*Exp[b[[1]]], 
    b[[2]]^2*Exp[b[[2]]] + pb*Exp[b[[2]]], 
    b[[3]]^2*Exp[b[[3]]] + pb*Exp[b[[3]]], 
    b[[4]]^2*Exp[b[[4]]] + pb*Exp[b[[4]]]}}]
dA[pb_?NumericQ, sb_?NumericQ] := Det[dCoeffMat[pb, sb]]
```

From here one can use `FindRoot` to get a value for `sb` that makes the determinat vanish given a value for `pb`. I use the real part of the determinant to avoid imaginary fuzz.

```
sbvals = 
 sb /. Table[FindRoot[Re[DA[pb, sb]] == 0, {sb, 1}], {pb, .1, 4., .1}]

(* Out[4217]= {0.0000893249467205, 0.000180282234353, 0.000271244538972, \
0.00036220809792, 0.000453172158726, 0.000544136470395, \
0.000635100925702, 0.000726065470127, 0.000817030074505, \
0.000907994720715, 0.000998959397339, 0.00108992409677, \
0.00118088881389, 0.00127185354457, 0.00136281828633, \
0.00145378303708, 0.0015447477952, 0.00163571255949, \
0.00172667732895, 0.00181764210281, 0.00190860688046, \
0.00199957166138, 0.00209053644524, 0.00218150123126, \
0.00227246601965, 0.00236343081001, 0.002454395602, 0.00254536039557, \
0.00281298528292, 0.00312767097318, 0.00341574060368, \
0.00368348997729, 0.00393511426993, 0.00417357535177, \
0.00440105694776, 0.00461922434613, 0.00482938236888, \
0.00503257643349, 0.00522965991584, 0.00542134060187} *)
```

Comment: @ Daniel Thanks. The results shows real values of `sb`. I am interested in both the `Re[sb]` and `Im[sb]`. How and where do I have to modify in your code ?

Comment: Try removing the `Re[...]` wrapper in that `FindRoot` and maybe give initial guess `{sb, 1+I}` (I don't have time to test this at the moment).

Comment: @ Daniel I have implemented your suggestion, now the imaginary parts of `sb` are visible. One last doubt (**hope not troubling you much :-)**) suppose in implementing `FindRoot` if I want to vary the initial guess (**as complex number**) with the purpose to search roots in wide range of complex plane. How can it be done??

Comment: You could use a `Table` that accounts for all the starting values. Something like `Table[FindRoot[Re[DA[pb, sb]] == 0, {sb, sbval}], {pb, .1, 4., .1}], {sbval, sbinits}]` where `sbinits` is the list of initial values you want to try.

Comment: @ Daniel Thanks